# Symbol for Area: $S$ or $A$

Tags: notation, area, math-history

I grew up (in China) with the symbol $S$ representing the area for a shape.

Some examples would be $S_{ABC}, S_{ABCD}$. Sometimes, for the area of a triangle, a triangle symbol is added, like: $S_{\triangle ABC}$.

However, it seems like that in the English-speaking world, the letter $A$ is more commonly used. [Area - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area)

[image: Common symbol for area in Wikipedia]

Someone pointed to me that the usage of the letter $S$ in China was under the influence of the Soviet Union, which eventually traces back to the French word: "superficie".

However, I do not speak French so that I can neither confirm nor deny this.

I am wondering which symbol is more commonly used worldwide. It is appreciated if you could share with me some of your knowledge about the symbold of area.

Comment: Area is both *surface* or *superficie* (also *aire*).

Comment: Personally I rarely see area being denoted by $S$ and almost always see $A$, but honestly it doesn't really matter all the much. So long as you are clear with your usage and definitions then you can really use whatever letter you want to denote area.

Comment: I think there's no agreement on this. The closer I get is that "area A" is a measure of "superface S". But I see both A,S usage for all meanings.

Comment: @SeraPhim I see it all the time. Whenever you want to find ($2$-dimensional) area on a manifold like object of $3$ or more dimensions, $S$ is often used.

Comment: @DonThousand Ah yeah that makes sense actually, I don't often do calculations with manifolds so I suppose that's why I wouldn't have seen that.

Comment: It happens in elementary math as well.  $S=4\pi r^2$ as the surface area of a sphere, for instance.

Comment: As there are plenty questions dealing with triangles,
most commonly and conveniently denoted as $\triangle ABC$
and $A$ is often used to define both a point and the angle at this point,
it is more convenient to use $S$ for the area, 
since using $A$ for the area in this case would be confusing.
There is another way to denote the area as $[ABC]$.

Comment: I don't think there is any standard symbol for area. In geometry the lower-case $s$ is usually used for half the perimeter of a triangle. Many authors use $\triangle$  (LaTex \triangle ) for the area of a triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I grew up in China too, but when I moved to Singapore, I was taught to write $\left[\Delta ABC \right]$ in Math Olympiads.

It takes a while to get used to.